# Automating the export of a legacy eclipse e4 application

Tags: eclipse, automation, export, wizard, e4

I've had a legacy eclipse e4 application product dropped in my lap. Plugin-based, circa 2014.
Right now the build process is "Run eclipse, then do these point-n-click things".  It needs the build & product-export processes automated. That is, made invoke-able from a command line.

Build automation was trivial. The Eclipse-created ant scripts work fine.

Product-export automation is proving quite annoying.

So far I see four options:

1. Invoke eclipse's Product Export Wizard from the command line.

   - Identifying the wizard specifics was easy (via the Plugin Selection Spy).
   - But there seems to be no way to make eclipse run a wizard from the command line.
2. Convert the existing plugin project to Maven/Tycho.

   - Theoretically modern and nice, but the details are messy.
   - Configure | Convert to Maven Project runs with no errors, but the resulting maven configuration is badly broken.
   - The project also has numerous out-of-date dependencies with no standard maven repo.
   - So a conversion to maven is far from straightforward.
3. Completely reorganize under a new maven/tycho project, just bringing over source files, icons, etc.

   - This still has the dependency issues, plus whatever unknowns crop up.
   - It would also trigger an in-depth QA cycle. I'd rather avoid that.
4. Create a second e4 application that (using EASE) runs the product-export wizard on the existing project.

   - IMO this is a blatant hack. I hate this idea, even though it would probably work.

Note: This is eclipse 4.15 on Windows. The installation is very fragile. It cannot be easily updated, because some of the code depends on the out-of-date dependencies.

I'd really prefer #1. Its non-invasive and bypasses a whole raft of issues.
But I'm stuck on the wizard-from-command-line.

Anyone done this particular type of eclipse automation?

Comment: Tycho is the way to go and by using POM-less it's even less messy than a normal Maven build. Learn more about here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html (see also [example repo](https://github.com/vogellacompany/tycho-example)). With current Tycho you can also include/convert Maven dependencies from a Maven repository as an OSGi bundle (see [release notes](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md)).

Comment: The export RCP wizard is no longer maintained so this should not be used, [tag:tycho] is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I've read all the vogella stuff.

I'm aware tycho is the modern way to write these plugins from scratch. I'd like to avoid that massive re-organization on a legacy project. The subsequent fallout of full test cycle by the Testing department would be weeks if not months of time.

Comment: Note: tycho is just a replacement for the old RCP export /buildsystem, plug-ins are still developed in the same way. It still uses the xxx.product file and all that stuff.